# How to Toggle Adjacent row (in a loop) in reactjs by using a function

Tags: reactjs

I have an api call and then data is stored in state. Then I render that data by using map and i have got a table. Look is over two rows of that table. One row is visible and other is hidden. The first row has got the toggle button. How can I create a function that toggle the second row for each record.

```
<table>
        {data.map(user => (
          <>
            <tr>
              <td>{user.name}</td>
              <td>
                <button>Toggle</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr className="additional-info">
              <td colSpan="2">{user.company.catchPhrase}</td>
            </tr>
          </>
        ))}
      </table>
```

i want to toggle the tr with class additional info.

the code is here

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-williamson-7m729

Answer (score 3, accepted):

toggling the visiblity of a component can be considered a state change. You need to store the state of whether a component is visible or not somewhere and because you are using hooks, a simple way is to use `setState` hook.

I have made a code sample that uses that approach [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-bush-ek9i7).

Comment: waow perfect solution. Thank you.